# I need help to configure a .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have this website url https://aplicaciones.com/newArchitecture/domain/honorarios/login/, then I need delete the word domain, domain is a directory into newArchitecture and honorarios its the name of my project or any project into domain, so when I put https://aplicaciones.com/newArchitecture/honorarios/login/ doesnt work, the web site add domain automatically.

This is my .htaccess in newArchitecture level:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /newArchitecture/domain/$1/$2 [L]`

This is my .htaccess in honorarios level (into domain):

`Options -Indexes`

delete extensions .PHP

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Friendly URL

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)src/controllers/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ src/controllers/index.php [L]
```

I tried with this :

`RewriteRule ^(\[^/\]+)/(.\*)$ /newArchitecture/domain/$1/$2 \[L\]`

Comment: _"This is my .htaccess in newArchitecture level:"_ - I don't think the server will actually look into that one in the first place here. You are requesting `/newArchitecture/honorarios/login/`, which does not match an existing file - so your root level .htaccess will rewrite this to `src/controllers/index.php` already. Do yourself a favor and don't spread this over multiple locations - handle it all in the root level .htaccess.